# Create table in database with php framework Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am new in Laravel 4

I am trying to develop a php web application with Laravel 4

I have the following question: It is possible to create  table in the database without using the terminal to run the following commands :

```
php artisan migrate: make create_users_table
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

the migration is a very convenient way of splitting your database into various changes, so you - or others from your team - can easily migrate to the current DB scheme. you can also seed the database with default data when using `artisan migrate:refresh --seed` which makes it a breeze to reset your DB content.

also it's *very* useful for unit tests.

surely you could create your own tables via `DB::statement('create table table_name')` but i strongly advise you to go the migrations route. you could also create one file for creating your initial tables instead of having to `artisan migrate:make` all of them.

Comment: i mean, you should follow the migration convention. it will make your life easier in the long run. if you just need to create some dummy tables, then you can always create them directly in some mysql tool.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use the `Schema` class as is used for creating migrations. So just use the following code in your controller or wherever you want.

```
Schema::create('create_users_table', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('something_else');
});
```

This is a nice reference for creating migrations:
http://laravelbook.com/laravel-migrations-managing-databases/